# Replace string in .html files with Django custom command

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I need to export my django project to static files. I'm using django-distill. Everything works fine except hrefs in main folder directory. So I decided to replace them with custom command after files were generated. However after few attempts I don't know why this function doesn't work. For example if even when I print out *soup* it show me empty string.

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help='change urls in each header to static version'


    def replace_urls(self):
        find_string_1 = 'href="/blog/"'
        find_string_2 = 'href="/contact/"'
        replace_string_1 = 'href="blog.html"'
        replace_string_2 = 'href="/contact.html"'

        exclude_dirs = ['media', 'static']

        for (_, dirs, files) in os.walk(f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/staticpage/'):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]
            for filepath in files:
                f = open(filepath, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
                if find_string_1 in soup:
                    soup.replace_with(replace_string_1)
                if find_string_2 in soup:
                    soup.replace_with(replace_string_2)
                f.close()


    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            self.replace_urls()
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'********** Command has been execute without any error **********'))
```

Comment: you realise `files` in the tuple resulting from [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk) is only the file name, not the file path? Not sure why you aren't seeing file not found errors when trying to open them. The first item in the tuple (that you're ignoring with `_`) is the path.

Comment: No I didn't. So I changed ```files``` with ```path``` and nothing changed. Command works without any error but is doing nothing.  I tried ```print (path.readlines())``` and it return empty lists

Comment: It should be `os.path.join(path, file)` if `path` is the first parameter of your tuple. You still need to append the filename

Comment: Set a debug breakpoint in your for loop and look at the values you're getting step by step in your debugger.